# What is the best way to calculate an average bounce rate that is split between two tracking ID's in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, bounce-rate, bounce

Say you were using one UA-ID for half a year and switched to another UA-ID in the second half of the year. How can you calculate the **overall average bounce rate** for the whole year? As far as my math goes, you can't average two percentages. One would need absolute numbers, so this got me thinking that maybe I can calculate the total bounces (not the rate) for each UA-ID, add them up, and later divide by "something" to get the "average" bounce rate over the two tracking ID's. Is my reasoning correct? If so how do I do this using the metrics supplied in Google Analytics? Or is there another way to calculate this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be:

```
Total number of bounces of each ID / Total number of sessions of each ID.
```

A session where the user only sees one page is a bounce.

Comment: Ow ok, maybe it's because it's weekend, but where can I see the amount of bounces in Google Analytics to try out your suggestion? I can't seem to find an oveview such as [this one](https://www.newfangled.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/stuffcontentmgrfiles2d00366ab3dd51004c8c8c1efe46e515bmiscentrances.jpg).

Comment: Found it, it's a segment called 'Bounced sessions' that you can use to quickly get the absolute amount and is slightly more accurate than doing num.sessions * bounce-rate :)